Realsense Camera with Isaac Ros SLAM quickstart guide: No RealSense devices were found
I am following the isaac ros visual slam guide (ROS2 Humble):
https://nvidia-isaac-ros.github.io/repositories_and_packages/isaac_ros_visual_slam/isaac_ros_visual_slam/index.html#quickstart
and after installing dependencies with
sudo apt-get install -y ros-humble-isaac-ros-examples ros-humble-isaac-ros-realsense
the next step of launching the demo fails due to "No RealSense device Detected".
Exploring further, it seems that before installing the dependencies, you can find the camera by running
rs-enumerate-devices
but afterwards, running the above returns no device detected but running it with sudo does detect the device.
The issue is that the next step involves ros2 and cant be used with sudo

Sounds to me like you may need a udev rule to set the permissions on the camera. For now you can try setting the permissions on the camera device directly (in /dev/).
